# How to pass EditText values to onCreate Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to pass an EditText value in my onCreate. (I don't think this is possible, but I don't know what to do!)

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
    }

    public void userClick(View v) {

      EditText mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1i); 
            String val1 = mEditText1.getText().toString();
            EditText mEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2i); 
            String val2 = mEditText2.getText().toString();

            double dVal1 = Double.parseDouble(val1); 
            double dVal2 = Double.parseDouble(val2);

            marker(dVal1,dVal2);

}

marker(double Lat, double Long) {

         googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Lat,Long)));
}
```

When I run the app, there is no marker in the Google Maps API (User sets latitude and longitude values via EditText)

I am unable to add the EditText values in onCreate as they will just become empty.

How can I pass the user set values in the onCreate method i.e.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
             googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(Lat,Long)));
        }
```

This obviously gives me an error as Lat and Long are unrecognisable.

I call the method below via onClick from EditText button which then calls the previous method where I want to put the EditText values

```
    public class UserInput extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.input);

}

    public void Input(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), UserInput.class);
            startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you invoking this activity from another one? In that case you can pass a payload to the Intent and acces this data via 'Intent intent = getIntent();' in 'onCreate'.

Comment: Yes, I am. Can you possible show me the code on how to solve this please? It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Post your Both Activity here..So it is easy to Solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass data form one activity to another, you can simply add it to the intent:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
    EditText editText = getViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(OtherActivity.KEY, message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and access this data in OtherActivity:

```
    public static final KEY = "my_data_key";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null) {
            String value = intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. I'm trying to pass the data from an onClick method to onCreate (both in the same class). Again, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Eggy you cannot pass something back to the onCreate of the same activity. you can only send it to a new activity

Answer (score 1):

If you have EditText and Map in one activity, you should to something like this.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    }
}

public void userClick(View v) {

  EditText mEditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1i); 
        String val1 = mEditText1.getText().toString();
        EditText mEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2i); 
        String val2 = mEditText2.getText().toString();

        double dVal1 = Double.parseDouble(val1); 
        double dVal2 = Double.parseDouble(val2);

        marker(dVal1,dVal2);

}

marker(double Lat, double Long) {
        LatLng curLocation = new LatLng(Lat, Long);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(curLocation).title("Marker"));
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(curLocation, 13);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Nope. I think Google Maps API executes before the marker and the zoom. Hence why there is no zoom

Comment: I'm just trying this snippet, and its works... Did you see map or just white screen?

Answer (score 0):

If your passing the edittext data from another activity, then you need to fetch the data in that activity and set the payload like this  :

```
 String lat = myLatitudeEditText.getText().toString();
 String long = myLongitudeEditText.getText().toString();
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class);
 myIntent.putExtra("lat",lat);
 myIntent.putExtra("long",long);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

Now in the onCreate of the second activity :

```
 String latitude = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lat");
 String longitude = getIntent().getExtras().getString("long");
```

Now you have got the text you passed in. Hope this resolves your query.